# for command "npm install" i cannot install node-modules, i get the npm ERR like This is related to npm not being able to find a file

Tags: reactjs, npm

I get this error in my powershell for command : "npm install"

PS C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Express-Js> npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Express-Js/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Express-Js\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-07T06_48_33_970Z-debug-0.log

I have install node-modules before also for another project, but i get this error first time.
in earlier projects of react i have used node-modules, at that time i have no such type of error.

Comment: Your project is called Express-Js? It says package.json or the folder is missing.

Comment: Are you located in the directory where the package.json is? Usually, this error is due to the fact that there is no package.json in the directory you are trying to do `npm install`. If it's a new project you can do `npm init` first, if it's a project that already has a project.json you just have to be sure you're in the correct directory.

Comment: Yes, problem is because I haven't created package.json file. So i have created that and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out why this error comes.
This is because I have not create "package.json" file in my folder.

I browse my question on internet and I got this solution.

So keep it in my that :

Make Sure There Is a Package.json File
When installing a package, npm needs to find the package.json file first. This file will list information about this package including name, version, description, keywords, dependencies, etc. If there is no package.json file, the npm install not working issue will occur. You can run the “ls -1” command to check whether there is a package.json file.

I get this solution from :
https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/npm-install-not-working.html

Hope, it will be helpful if someone has same error.